# Apache Maven: How to package a classifier inside another classifier

Tags: maven

I have two projects A and B. Project A is packaged into 2 jars with classifiers `com` and `exec` respectively. I want to package Project B into 2 jars:

1. `com` that contains `com` classifier of **A** as its dependency
2. `exec` that contains `exec` classifier of **A** as its dependency

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Is there a reason why having them as jar with classifiers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different classifiers always have the same POM. Therefore they have the same dependencies.

So the answer is: This is not possible.